# Customize VisualStudio syntax highlighting even more

Tags: visual-studio, ide, visual-studio-2005, syntax-highlighting

I am wondering if it is possible to set VisualStudio IDE so it highlights private/protected/public variables of the class differently as well as change formatting on locals (i.e. variables that are either passed in or declared inside a function, like [this](http://www.wholetomato.com/products/features/bold.asp)).

I did not find any such options in the normal Fonts and Colors menu of VS. Also a search on SO reveals that (at least as of 2 years ago) only add-ons provide such features. But is there a way to manually edit some file? Just because we don't get a nice UI to edit, doesn't mean underlying framework automatically doesn't support it. I mean add-ons have to plug into something to do their magic in the editor. Any insights into this issue?

Thanks!

**EDIT:** I have found the following information on MSDN [Syntax Highlighting (Managed Package Framework)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165041(VS.80).aspx). But the explanation/examples given are woefully inadequate. Does anyone know of a more extensive docs/tutorials/etc. for MPF?

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong (probably am) but I think plugins that do what you want replace the default highlighter in Visual Studio, so I don't think there is a file you can edit.  As far as I know, you need a plugin.  ReSharper might do this...I'm not sure though (I don't use it)

Comment: My greatest point of contention with all the plug-ins for this (I found several), is that they do so much more. And I need none of those extras. I need this one feature. Even within this one feature of syntax highlighting, I need like 10% of it. I am looking for docs on how to develop a plug-in for this (see my edit to the question). Thanks for  the info!